# .pdb file not getting created in "TemporaryASP.NET Folder" - MVC 4/VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 projects created under a solution.While one project is loading the symbols the other class library is failing. It is creating the dll + pdb in project bin/debug but creating only the dll in temporary asp folder.For debugging, the symbols are being checked from the Temp asp folder which is not finding the pdb.The other project is creating in the bin/debug and is succesully creating in temp asp folder as well.Can anyone help why the .pdb is not getting created there ?